# Control scrollview programmatically — Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have an scrollview with some buttons on it. When one button is clicked I want it to be on top of the screen so that the button.frame.origin.y is the self.view.frame.origin.y. How do I do this?

Comment: Remember that a view's `frame` and it's superview's `frame` are, by definition, in different coordinate systems. If you want to compare the position of a view to that of its superview, you should use the same coordinate system. Either use the view's `frame` and the parent's `bounds`, or convert both frames to some common coordinate system with a method such as `-convertRect:toWindow:`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [scrollView setContentOffset:sender.frame.origin animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: This may scroll the horizontal axis also.  It's not clear if that's desired or not.  The fix would be to construct a CGPoint using the sender's origin.y, and the scrollview's current contentOffset.x.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated` method.

To scroll the view to the desired frame when the button is pressed.

For example:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:desireFrameFromButton];
}
```

Comment: that moves the button to somewhere visible on the screen, but I want it to be exactly on the top